# Python: how to split string by groups Alpha-numeric vs numeric

Tags: python, string, substring, numeric, alphanumeric

Lets say I have Strings like:
`"H39_M1", "H3_M15", "H3M19", "H3M11", "D363_H3", "D_128_H17_M50"`

How can I split them every single one into a list of substrings?
like this:

`["H39", "M1"], "[H3, "Min15"], ["H3","M19"], ["H3","M11"], ["D363","H3"], ["D128","H17","M50"]`

and afterwards: switch places of alphanumeric-group and numeric group,
like this:
`["39H", "1M"], "[3H, "15Min"], ["3H","19M"], ["3H","11M"], ["363D","3H"],["128D","17H","50M"]`

length of numbers-group and of alphanumeric group varys as you can see.
also "_" underscores can divide them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might suggest using `re.findall` here with `re.sub`:

```py
inp = "H3M19"
inp = re.sub(r'([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)', r'\2\1', inp)
parts = re.findall(r'[0-9]+[A-Z]+', inp)
print(parts)
```

This prints:

```
['3H', '19M']
```

The first `re.sub` step converts `H3M19` into `3H19M`, by capturing the letter and numeric pairs and then swapping them.  Then, we use `re.findall` to find all number/letter pairs in the swapped input.

Comment: modified it a little and :
`
import re
inp = "D1378_Min199_H4999"
inp = inp.replace("_","")
inp = re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9999]+)', r'\2\1', inp)
parts = re.findall(r'[0-9]+[A-Z]+', inp)
print(parts)` does the job ^^

Comment: @HR_quantile Note that `[0-9]+` and `[0-9999]+` basically match the same thing.  `[0-9]+` matches any number which consists of one or more digits from 0 to 9.